# Capturing log output on an iOS device and transferring that file to host using mobiledevice framework

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-ui-automation, ios5

This question is about logging with iOS.

I am using the command line version of instruments to run an application on iOS. And that part works fine.

What I am wondering, is how to capture the log output of the running application? That is, to do the equivalent of syslog output without jail breaking the device?

I've made slight modifications to the application to capture stdout and stderr to a log file. This is kept in the Documents folder of the applications (i.e. /Documents/syslog.txt). I can copy this folder over using Xcode's organizer which shows it to be in a package_name/AppData/Documents/syslog.txt file. However, I would like to do this programmatically for our test automation framework.

A co-worker suggests using the AFC protocol (which Xcode uses), but I want to be sure that is the best approach to take. So far it looks like it is, so how does one use AFC and/or other mobiledevice API's to copy the file?

There are suggestions to look into projects on github, but I would just like a straight example of what it takes to do this task in C code.

Thanks,

Jose

Comment: Ok, I will answer my own question. I ended up using expect to be the glue to install the app, log syslog to local host file, run instruments, and then uninstall the app. I used fruitstrap to install the app (modified by another QA engineer to add uninstall functionality). I used syslog (not syslog_relay) code posted on this forum (I think. Might have been somewhere else) to get the syslog output from the device and redirected the output into a file. I then got the spawn id's for the syslog process and the instruments process and waited on those to finish. Then finally I uninstalled the app.